# Can't get anything other than a 404 after creating a new wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, apache

Can anyone please help here?

I have the latest apache2 and wordpress installed on Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is that I cannot create a new page in wordpress and then have access to it in my browser i.e. example.net/newpage I just get a 404, I have check my permalink settings and they are set properly. Wordpress says the page is created, and I can edit it no problem within the wordpress interface, I can also view it if it's just saved as a draft, as soon as I publish I get a 404.

My wordpress virtualhost settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.net
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                <Directory /var/www/html>
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
                        DirectoryIndex index.php
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/html/wp-content>
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The logs from "tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log" when I create the new page then try to access it straight away:

```
$myip - - [24/Jul/2017:16:57:04 +0200] "POST /wp-admin/post.php HTTP/1.1" 302 520 "http://example.net/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&wp-post-new-reload=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
$myip - - [24/Jul/2017:16:57:04 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/post.php?post=12&action=edit&message=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 26740 "http://example.net/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&wp-post-new-reload=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
$myip - - [24/Jul/2017:16:57:05 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=oembed-cache&post=12 HTTP/1.1" 200 382 "http://example.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=12&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
$myip - - [24/Jul/2017:16:57:08 +0200] "GET /newpage/ HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "http://example.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=12&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

For folder and file permissions I ran:

```
find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I have tried everything I can think of including setup tutorials and reinstalling wordpress and mysql from the beginning but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you change permalinks in settings to "Plain"?

Comment: Then the page shows up in the browser

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2017/07/wordpress-fixing-not-found-error-when-using-pretty-permalinks/) article, it could be due to **mod_rewrite** module not being loaded in Apache.

Comment: Slightly beat you to it and found out if i ran: "a2enmod rewrite" then that also fixed it. Wow hours of pain for that! Thanks for the help!